# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to add objects that are in an array to an `NSDictionary` based on their position inside of the `NSArray`, but the app crashes as soon as the `NSDictionary` is allocated. Any ideas why?

```
NSString *venue_title = [venues objectAtIndex:[actionSheet tag]];
NSString *venue_address = [venues_full_address objectAtIndex:[actionSheet tag]];
NSString *venue_lat = [venues_lat objectAtIndex:[actionSheet tag]];
NSString *venue_lng = [venues_lng objectAtIndex:[actionSheet tag]];        
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@", venue_title, venue_address, venue_lat, venue_lng);        
NSDictionary *venue_details_dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:venue_title, venue_address, venue_lat, venue_lng, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"address", @"lat", "lng", nil]];
```

I see all the right values when I NSLog the objects, but the NSDictionary makes the app crash with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I have `NSZombies` enabled, but nothing is being shown when it crashes like it would regularly show. Any ideas on what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the text of the crash report and any preceding error messages into your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *venue_details_dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:venue_title, venue_address, venue_lat, venue_lng, nil]
   forKeys:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"address", @"lat", "lng", nil]];
```

You forgot the `@` on `"lng"`.  Boom.

Comment: Wow. So stupid. I cannot believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: This also works ;-)

    NSDictionary *venue_details_dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:venue_title, venue_address, venue_lat, venue_lng, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"address", @"lat", @"lng", nil]];

Comment: Please file a bug -- the compiler should be able to catch that.

Answer (score 2):

For more clarity that makes errors like this easier to see try:

```
NSDictionary *venue_details_dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    venue_title,   @"name",
    venue_address, @"address",
    venue_lat,     @"lat",
    venue_lng,     @"lng",
    nil];
```